# PHP script return responseText to AJAX From POST? Want To Return Message with Ajax POST

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

I am trying to make a scheme where Ajax calls upload.php and upload.php will return success or failure in a message. I tried using echo "successs" in the php script, hopeing that xhr.responseText would receive the message. But instead alert(xhr.responseText) is a blank line. Then it occured to me, does xhr.responseText only work with GET and not POST? If this is it, how can I have it to where the php script can return a custom message? I do not  want to use the HTTP status codes...I rather learn how to do custom messages if possible.

**No Jquery please.**

```
<?php
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$path = "/trunk";
$name = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$success = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $name);
if ($success) {
    echo "good";
} else {
    echo "bad";
}
?>
}

function uploadPHP() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
       form = document.getElementById("uploadForm");

    xhr.open("POST", "php/upload.php", true);
    xhr.send(new FormData(form));
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the following:

```
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.status==200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
```

Since you're doing a file upload, the response is going to take a bit of time to be generated. This function will run every time the state of the request changes and only out the response when everything has completed.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I am looking for. I want fire back a custom message to the client, and regardless right now the xhr.responseText shows a blank line...so the root issue still exists. Also, I am only using small files like 300kb on a localhost webserver...so times are quick.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the XHR call is going to return whatever your script would print to the screen. I'm not sure why you would want to avoid using status codes. All the status code is doing is checking to make sure your request has completed successfully before trying to print the message in your script.